# Files created in other tasks not packed with bootRun

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to build and pack a react app with my spring backend (so they can be hosted together). I have the react app under `src/main/js` and what I need to do is to build it then copy the contents of the build folder to `resources/static` then copy the index.html from there to `resources/templates` (so my main spring controller can serve it)

I have followed multiple tutorials in the topic and even though non of them worked completely, I've managed to come up with this solution (only adding the tasks part of my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
val jsDir = "src/main/js"
val staticDir = "src/main/resources/static"
val templatesDir = "src/main/resources/templates"

tasks.register<YarnTask>("installDependencies") {
    args.set(listOf("install"))
    execOverrides.set {
        setWorkingDir(jsDir)
    }
}

tasks.register<YarnTask>("buildReact") {
    dependsOn("installDependencies")
    args.set(listOf("build"))
    execOverrides.set {
        setWorkingDir(jsDir)
    }
}

tasks.register<Delete>("preCleanup"){
    delete(staticDir)
    delete(templatesDir)
    mkdir(staticDir)
    mkdir(templatesDir)
}

tasks.register<Delete>("cleanup"){
    delete("$staticDir/index.html")
    delete("$jsDir/build")
}

tasks.register<Copy>("copyBuild"){
    dependsOn("buildReact")
    from("$jsDir/build")
    into(staticDir)
}

tasks.register<Copy>("copyTemplate"){
    dependsOn("copyBuild")
    from("$staticDir/index.html")
    into(templatesDir)
    finalizedBy("cleanup")
}

tasks.register<Task>("buildWeb"){
    dependsOn("preCleanup")
    finalizedBy("copyTemplate")
}

tasks.bootRun{
    dependsOn("buildWeb")
}
```

(I'm using [this](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin) Gradle Node plugin)

Looking at my files, the build is successful but when I navigate to the url of my app I either see an error page (on the first build) or the previous version of my react app. Almost seems like the `bootRun` task saves the state of the files before running my tasks so it always gets the previous version of the react files

I could solve this problem by creating a new tasks that depends on my `buildWeb` and is finalised by `bootRun` but it would just be nicer if `bootRun` could automatically do the job.

```
tasks.register<Task>("bootRunWithWeb"){
    dependsOn("buildWeb")
    finalizedBy("bootRun")
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `finalizedBy`? Is it to avoid putting multiple tasks in `dependsOn`? Not sure if it plays a role but your use of `finalizedBy` is not in line with how it should be used according to the docs, e.g. for tasks which should run no matter if the task itself fails (for example, in your last example you don't want to run `bootRun` even if `buildWeb` fails, right?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. After scanning through the docs again, I've realised that you are right.. but then should I just chain these tasks together with dependsOn? Maybe it is just me but saying that ```buildWeb``` depends on ```cleanup``` (because that would be the last on in the chain) just seems a bit odd

Comment: I'm not saying you have to put ALL dependencies in a single task target. You could have the layout you have now, just put all `finalizedBy` as `dependsOn` instead and to control order of dependencies (n.b. that TYPICALLY dependencies ARE resolved in the order they are listed) just add `mustRunAfter` or `shouldRunAfter` on the task in question. These commands ensure that WHENEVER both the target to which `mustRunAfter` or `shouldRunAfter` is added and the other referred target are both currently queued to be executed, the target with these commands will run before the other target.

Comment: I see, I will try that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootRun has the main source set’s output on its classpath but you are copying things to one of its input locations. It is the processResources task that copied resources from the input location to the output location. If processResources runs before you add files to src/main/resources, the new files will be missed.

To fix this, you could either make processResources depend on buildWeb or you could copy the files into sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir.

Comment: Made ```processResources``` dependent on my task and it works perfectly. Is the same task used with ```bootJar```? Actually, what is the best way to discover such dependencies?

Comment: Yes, although not directly. `bootJar` consumes, among other things, the output of the main source set. Gradle will therefore make sure that tasks involved in producing that output have run before `bootJar` runs. Running with `--console=plain` can help with seeing what’s going on. Build scans can be useful too. There are also various plugins available that will show you the task graph.